# Can I bring chocolate from Belgium to Georgia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, belgium, georgia-country

I would like to bring some Belgian chocolate to Georgia (the country) as a gift for a friend. Is that allowed?

I've tried to find some information about it, since sometimes it's forbidden to import products containing milk into some countries, but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: Most countries allow commercially manufactured chocolates. Just remember to declare it at customs. Not declaring it may cause you to be fined, even if it is allowed.

Comment: "Declaring it" as in "taking the red exit"? As far as I know, there are no immigration cards when flying from Europe to Georgia on Georgian Airways.

Answer (score 2):

The only regulations they have is on alcohol and cigarettes. I noticed everyone inside the Tbilisi airport smoking cigarettes, so i do not think chocolates will be a problem at all. I was literally choking on cigarette smoke inside that airport.

I tried to research it online but did not find much, although i did find [this](https://www.export.gov/article?id=Georgia-Import-Tariffs):

> An 18 percent value added tax (VAT) applies to most imported goods. 
>   Fixed excise tax rates apply to certain goods such as alcoholic
>   drinks, ethyl alcohol, ethyl petrol for cars, and cigarettes.  The
>   customs value of goods for customs clearance is defined based on the
>   customs declaration.  Export, transit, and re-export of goods are
>   exempt from customs duties and fees.  Chapter 39(1) of the Georgian
>   Tax Code defines the amount of the customs tariffs and exemptions.
>   Once every 30 day period, individuals are allowed to import the
>   following goods free of customs duties, VAT, and excise duties within
>   the following limits: Import of vegetables, fruit (including dried),
>   tea, coffee, macaroni, bakery, sugar, confections (with the exception
>   of chocolate), sausages, **milk and dairy products that have a maximum
>   total weight of 30 kg,** and a total value of less than 500 GEL ($222).

As long as you aren't bringing in over 30kg of chocolate, you should be okay.